# How does SQL Server Mgmt Studio access remote file system using SQL credentials?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Does anyone know what code/tools Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio uses to access the file system of a remote system when performing a backup or restore operation? There has to be a hook through SQL Server since it can use SQL credentials, doesn't there?

Comment: I believe it uses BACKUP DATABASE TO DISK, which instructs server to make backup. So, the one who writes to disk is server, not SSMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSMS uses sql commands to control the server, so you can run Sql Profiler (if you have it) and see what command are executed on server side.

Get availables drives:

```
-- Fixed
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_fixeddrives 
-- Remote
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_fixeddrives 1 
-- Removable
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_fixeddrives 2 
-- CD-ROM
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_fixeddrives 3
```

Get folders:

```
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_dirtree 'C:', 1, 1
-- or
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_dirtree 'C:\Windows', 1, 1
```

Check if specific file exists:

```
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_fileexist 'c:\pagefile.sys'
```

Of course, you are limited at least by permission granted to an account under which Sql Server runs.

Answer (score 0):

During the installation of SQL Server on the remote machine, it is configured.

Commonly it is set to the `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORKSERVICE` Account or `NT AUTHORITY\LOCALSERVICE` Account.

It can be configured after-the-fact using `Sql Server Configuration Manager`.
It is described as the `Log On As:` Property.